# php command line change text output

Tags: php, terminal, command-line-interface, onchange

I want to know is it possible to change some output for special php cli base application to change some value on terminal not echo new one. for example this is cli application.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$percent = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {

    echo $percent . "\n";

    sleep(1);

    $percent++;
}

/**
0
1
...
*/
```

It's a simple app to show the user the percentage. So we must update it after each loop in this example, rather than append it. I want to change percent not show new one.

Comment: Do you mean `newline` instead of `new one`? If not, please clarify what new one you mean.

Comment: @Oldskool new one. alias `update`

Comment: OK, then I ask again, new one of what? What new entitity are we talking about? The "new" percentage? There are 100 new percentages in your loop...

Comment: @Oldskool it's an simple app to show user number of percentage. so we must update it after each loop in this example.

Comment: Oh ok, now I get it. I updated the questions to reflect this better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `\r` instead of `\n`. `\r` is a carriage return, it will jump back to the beginning of the line without a newline.

```
$percent = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    echo $percent . "\r";
    sleep(1);
    $percent++;
}
```

This is working on Windows, Linux and MacOS

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the operating system the terminal runs in?

Comment: it's the latest solution. if i have a sentences and i want to change lot of variable on that sentences i must do it with my calculate and etc ...

Comment: This works on Linux, Windows and MacOS (just tested all of them).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for what you need (tested and verified on a Linux (CentOS) machine):

```
for ($percent = 0; $percent <= 100; $percent++) {
    echo $percent;
    sleep(1);
    // Print one or more backspaces, erasing current character(s)
    echo str_repeat("\x08", strlen($percent));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This actually depends on your terminal (emulator) type, not on the language used. Have a few tries using the backspace character (0x08) to 'erase' the current content, then output the new content.

Comment: another solution wasn't available ?